# Angular 2 JS app cannot load forms module

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to import the angular forms module in a Javascript Angular 2 app.

**app.module.js**

```
(function(app) {

  app.AppModule =
    ng.core.NgModule({
      imports: [ ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.forms.FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ app.AppComponent, app.Counter, app.Productlist ],
      bootstrap: [ app.AppComponent ]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

And in my html template I attempt to use the form module with:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName" />
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'FormsModule' of undefined(…)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined(…)
```

Note: the project and templates do work without the forms module, so how do I properly import the form module?